# Getting "TypeError: loc must be int" when trying to insert() a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a weird problem that only shows up when I set a variable to a number using index.
I have a dataframe, df, 427 rows x 335 columns.

Here is the code to set the variable:

```
first_val = df[df.loc[0]=="Density"].index[0]
```

This sets it to "9".

Then I do the following to insert columns:

```
df=df.T
#Add SD after every variable
sdrm=[sd, rep, met]
i = first_val
j = len(df.columns)-1


while i < j:
    if df.loc[1,i] != sd and df.loc[1,i] != rep and df.loc[1,i] != met:
        if df.loc[1,i+1] != sd:
            print(i)
            df.insert(i+1,sd,np.nan)
            df.columns = pd.RangeIndex(df.columns.size)
            df.loc[1,i+1]=sd
    i+=1
    j = len(df.columns)-1
```

I get error:

```
   1151         if not isinstance(loc, int):
-> 1152             raise TypeError("loc must be int")
   1153 
   1154         # insert to the axis; this could possibly raise a TypeError

TypeError: loc must be int
```

That seems to be caused by `---> 11             df.insert(i+1,sd,np.nan)`

The weird part is that if I set the variable manually it doesn't give an error:

```
first_val = 9
```

This runs fine.
Why does setting the variable with the index cause an issue?
I added `.copy()` thinking that would help and it didn't:

```
first_val = df[df.loc[0]=="Density"].index[0].copy()
```

I want to set the variable based on a condition, the first time the string "Density" shows up in df[0].
Is there another way to do this?

Edit:

Full error trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-145-7eae051d9c6d> in <module>
      9         if df.loc[1,i+1] != sd:
     10             print(i)
---> 11             df.insert(i+1,sd,np.nan)
     12             df.columns = pd.RangeIndex(df.columns.size)
     13             df.loc[1,i+1]=sd

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in insert(self, loc, column, value, allow_duplicates)
   3471         value = self._sanitize_column(column, value, broadcast=False)
   3472         self._data.insert(loc, column, value,
-> 3473                           allow_duplicates=allow_duplicates)
   3474 
   3475     def assign(self, **kwargs):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in insert(self, loc, item, value, allow_duplicates)
   1150 
   1151         if not isinstance(loc, int):
-> 1152             raise TypeError("loc must be int")
   1153 
   1154         # insert to the axis; this could possibly raise a TypeError

TypeError: loc must be int
```

Trying `first_val = df[df.loc[0]=="Density"].index[0]` has the same effect.

When I try `first_val.dtype()` I get `TypeError: 'numpy.dtype' object is not callable`

`type(first_val)` gives `numpy.int64`

Comment: Can you include the whole error trace?

Comment: what is type of first_val after you do df[df.loc[0]=="Density"].index[0]? Is it an str?

Comment: can you please try first_val = df.loc[df.loc[0]=="Density"].index[0]?

Comment: @TimHilt Updated the question with edits

Comment: @ArtyomAkselrod "numpy.int64"

Comment: @Ragnar same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your trace error says, you need to use int for loc. Now you use numpy.int64 which is not an pure int type in python. Please, try:

```
first_val = int(df[df.loc[0]=="Density"].index[0])
```

As a result `type(first_val)` gives `int`.

But be careful, if your df is extremely large. Simple int range is between (0 to 4294967295) and np.uint64 has range between (0 to 18446744073709551615)

Comment: Thanks this was an easy fix!